# Naming methods and passing values

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

Taking the below method as an example:

```
-(void)myMethodName:(int)xCoordinate yCoordinate:(int)yCoordinate
```

When I write the method in my code [self etc...], Xcode does its auto complete which tells me what the second value is for but never the first (see pic).

[image]

Is there any way I can also include the 'description' for the first value of a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```
-(void)myMethodNameWithXCoordinate:(int)xCoordinate yCoordinate:(int)yCoordinate
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of how you name your method. It autocompletes the entire method name. If the method name is descriptive of its parameters, then you'll see it in the autocomplete.

Comment: @SamBudda: Well, I'll be concrete here, since good method names should read naturally. So for example, if this method is about moving something around, you might have `-(void)moveToXCoord:(int)xCoord yCoord:(int)yCoord`. Basically, you write your method name to include *what it does* as well as *what it's doing that to*.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the methods are usually defined in objective C

```
- (int)addX:(int)x toY:(int)y {
      int sum = x + y;
      return sum;
  }
```

Like others have said rename your method this way and it will make things clearer

```
-(void)moveStuffFromXCoordinate:(int)xCoordinate toYCoordinate:(int)yCoordinate
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Apple Documentation on coding guidelines for cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) when naming methods with parameters the word before the argument should describe the argument.

Make the word before the argument describe the argument.

**Right** `- (id)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)aTag;`

The above is right because it describes the argument as a `Tag` where as the below doesn't describe the argument as anything.

**Wrong** `- (id)taggedView:(int)aTag;`

So in your case

**Wrong** `-(void)myMethodName:(int)xCoordinate yCoordinate:(int)yCoordinate;`

it should be

**Right** `-(void)myMethodNameForXCoordinates:(int)xCoordinate andYCoordinate:(int)yCoordinate;`